# WPF RichTextBox - get current line

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

How to get the current line (and remove) in WPF's `RichTextBox`?

Winforms has `RichTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex()` which is not found in WPF.

Comment: Do you want to remove a paragraph or a specific line? because in a RichTextBox, lines change when you change the size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a paragraph by calling `Paragraph para=CaretPosition.Paragraph;`

If you want to remove this paragraph, use `Document.Blocks.Remove(para)`. if you want to remove the line in which the Caret is, you should find two `TextPointer`s: The one at the begining of the line and the one at the end. Call these two `tp1` and `tp2`. You can remove the line by

```
TextRange tr=new textRange(tp1,tp2);
tr.Text="";
```

If I've understood correctly, let me know to explain how you can get the two TextPointers

Comment: Please do if you can explain how to get first line of of richtextbox and also is it bolded, underlined etc